# Footer Class on my Web Page

Tags: css, css-position

I have a web app with multiple canvases displayed on a single page. This makes the page very long and a lot of scrolling is necessary from the client.

To enhance user accessibility I have added  a footer class:

HTML:

```
<footer class="site-footer">
  <a href="#" style="text-align:inherit; position: relative;
     vertical-align: inherit; left: 399px; width: 146px;"
     data-scroll="claims">TOP OF THE PAGE</a>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```css
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after 
{
  height: 52px; 
}
.site-footer 
{ 
  background: orange;
  border:2px solid white;
}
```

This allows the user to directly jump up to the top of the page once they have scrolled to the very bottom of the page.

I was wondering if there was a way to make this footer available at all views of the page, and not just only at the very bottom. That way the client may choose to scroll to the very top of the page from only the middle of the page and not the very bottom.

I have tried playing around with the CSS property position, but to no avail. Can anyone help?

Also further suggestions on how to make my user experience cooler is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Smooth Page Scroll to Top with jQuery](http://gazpo.com/2012/02/scrolltop/) for an example of this type of effect.

Here is a [demo](http://gazpo.com/downloads/tutorials/jquery/scrolltop/).

Here is the code for that:

CSS:

```
.scrollup{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    opacity:0.3;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:50px;
    right:100px;
    display:none;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background: url('icon_top.png') no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Scroll</a>
...
Bunch of content here, big enough to make the page scroll in order to read it all.
...
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
            } 
            else {
                $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
            }
        }); 

        $('.scrollup').click(function(){
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Used fixed positioning:

```
.site-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

`position: fixed` means the element will be removed from the normal document flow and positioned relative to the viewport (browser window).

The code above will force your `.site-footer` element to always be visible at the bottom left of the screen (use `right: 0` instead if you'd like it on the right side).  Some additional code may be required, but it's not possible to tell that from what you have provided.

Comment: Add `right: 0;` in addition to `left: 0;` with your `.site-footer` class to make it span the entire width of the browser. Additionally, as Ennui mentioned, `position: fixed;` will take your footer out of the document flow, so you'll need to compensate for that offset so that your content doesn't get hidden behind the footer. In my example I just added `margin-bottom: 52px;` to the `body` element to match your footer height. This isn't really the best way to handle it, but if you know your footer will always be that height, it will suffice. http://jsfiddle.net/qm8Tu/2/

Comment: I dont want the footer to span across the entire width of my browser. Just a tiny centered footer is what I am looking for.